# Veracode issue in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, veracode

I am getting veracode issue in the below line

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "studentName" value = "<%=viewBean.getStudName()%>">
```

The issue is on `<%=viewBean.getStudName()%>`
Here, the issue reported is "Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML tags in a web page(Basic XSS). I have tried the fix given in cwe.mitre.org but I could not apply it properly. Can anyone help on this how to overcome the issue?

Comment: Can you please mark which answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<c:out value=${viewBean.studName}/>
```

instead it escapes `XML`

Answer (score 0):

As per `CWE`,

> The software receives input from an upstream component, but it does
>   not neutralize or incorrectly neutralizes special characters such as
>   "<", ">", and "&" that could be interpreted as web-scripting elements
>   when they are sent to a downstream component that processes web pages.

You need to escape html, can be done if you use `jstl` tags as @jigar suggested.

Some info on SO about to fix the error ,

1. [Veracode - Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801940/veracode-improper-neutralization-of-script-related-html-tags-in-a-web-page-ba)
2. [How to fix Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) with error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912509/how-to-fix-improper-neutralization-of-script-related-html-tags-in-a-web-page-ba)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "hidden" name = "studentName" value = "<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(viewBean.getStudName())%>">
```

Used like this. Its working now as adviced by @Jigar Joshi and @ San Krish

Answer (score 0):

Include below jstl taglib in jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

and use

```
value="${fn:escapeXml(viewBean.getStudName())}"
```

If using JSTL core `<c:out/>`, you can use `escapeXml="true"` to avoid XSS.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use html encoding while printing the value . so it is giving error . so it should be encoded as
value = "<%=ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHtml(viewBean.getStudName())%>">

you need to import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI and org.owasp.esapi.Encoder.

This will surely resovlve issues ..