# How do I fix cwe-80 xss in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, xss

```
<% 
String ans = ""; 
ans = SpecialCharacter.getEscapeString((String)request.getAttribute("ans"));
%>

<input type="text" class="txt long" name="ans" id="ans" maxlength="48" value="${ans}"/>
```

I have code like above, and I am using template literals already to substitute value but veracode scan still shows me that it is xss vulnerable. How do I fix in such case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646894/veracode-issue-in-jsp

Comment: that's what i used `value="${ans}"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612746/how-to-fix-veracode-cross-site-scripting-cwe-id-80-basic-xss-use-of-it

Answer (score 0):

Use [OWASP Java Encoder](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project) use `<input type="text" class="txt long" name="ans" id="ans" maxlength="48" value="<%= Encode.forHtmlAttribute(ans)%>" />`