# Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80) for response.BinaryWrite

Tags: c#, xss, veracode

I tried by applying encode for filename but still getting veracode error at **response.BinaryWrite(data);**

Below is my code:

```
                    WebClient req = new WebClient();
                    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                    response.Clear();
                    response.ClearContent();
                    response.ClearHeaders();
                    response.Buffer = true;
                    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + XSSSec.Encoder.HtmlEncode(FileName) + "\"");
                    byte[] data = req.DownloadData(FilePath);
                    response.BinaryWrite(data);
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.SuppressContent = true;
```

Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) with error message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912509/how-to-fix-improper-neutralization-of-script-related-html-tags-in-a-web-page-ba)

Comment: Amy - HTML encode wont work for byte[]. Veracode error is at response.BinaryWrite