# Why does veracode consider $(document) a flaw?

Tags: veracode

Today when i rescanned veracode reopened a bunch of lines with things like...

```
$(document).off('click.applicationmenu open-applicationmenu close-applicationmenu keydown.applicationmenu');
$(document).on('open-applicationmenu', () => {...
$(document).trigger($.Event('keydown', { keyCode: 27, which: 27 }));
```

Why is `$(document)` considered a "Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS" flaw ? And also why suddenly today and never before on any other scans.

This seems like it would be fine to me or how to fix/mitagate if its not?

Comment: Maybe ask Veracode (the company).

Comment: Yeah i scheduled a session but its not until next week. So hoping someone had some thoughts meanwhile.

Comment: Added the error its all "Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS"

Comment: Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912509/how-to-fix-improper-neutralization-of-script-related-html-tags-in-a-web-page-ba) (which is not a duplicate), this leads me to think that veracode seems to think that `document` is a string that is unsanitised. That doesn't look correct though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was something they added and removed to the scan results. It does not seem to be reported anymore.