# Veracode Scan XSS issue for Response.BinaryWrite() method

Tags: c#, xss, veracode

While running the veracode scan, a vulnerability has been thrown for the below line:

```
Page.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.GetBuffer());
```

Where, stream is an object of **System.IO.MemoryStream.**

I have tried the below line of code

```
Page.Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(stream.GetBuffer())))
```

But, the same issue appears again in the scan.

Some details of the scan error:

> Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page
>   (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80)

Comment: Have you tried to check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912509/how-to-fix-improper-neutralization-of-script-related-html-tags-in-a-web-page-ba) and encode or escape the response?

Comment: The weakness description is pretty clear _The software receives input from an upstream component, but it does not neutralize or incorrectly neutralizes special characters such as "<", ">", and "&" that could be interpreted as web-scripting elements when they are sent to a downstream component that processes web pages._ (from [here](https://infosec.cert-pa.it/cwe-80.html))

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912509/how-to-fix-improper-neutralization-of-script-related-html-tags-in-a-web-page-ba ?

Comment: Ok, let's zoom out, you are trying to respond some stream from .... to ... where? What kind of app? MVC, webforms? I have a feeling you just forgot to set some header or are responding some file the wrong way.